# Error on build JavaScript project Travis-CI

Tags: javascript, gulp, travis-ci

I have a project which I am building locally with **Gulp.js**. But when I push it to GitHub and Travis start building it. I get the following error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-concat'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/thyagostall/freecell/gulpfile.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

The `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp gulp-concat gulp-connect gulp-html-replace gulp-eslint
script: gulp
```

Also my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

var distDir = './build/',
    sourceDir = './src/';

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: distDir,
        port: 2345,
        livereload: true
    });
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['build', 'images', 'styles', 'vendor']);
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src(sourceDir + '**/*.{jpg,png,gif}')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir));
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(sourceDir + '**/*.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir));
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    gulp.src([sourceDir + '**/utility.js', sourceDir + '**/game_events.js', sourceDir + '**/memento.js', sourceDir + '**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('vendor', function() {
    gulp.src(sourceDir + '**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'vendor': 'vendor.js',
            'js': 'main.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir));
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    gulp.src(sourceDir + '**/*.js')
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'images', 'styles', 'vendor']);
```

Is there any obvious thing I am missing?

Comment: You should inspect your build log and make sure that `gulp-concat` installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `.travis.yml` to this:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp
script: gulp
```

You only need to install `gulp` globally because this provides the `gulp` commmand line tool. Per the [official npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally):

> There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally. You choose which kind of installation to use based on how you want to use the package.
>
> If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally.

Second, I did some sleuthing on your github account (linked from your StackOverflow profile) and found the [project](https://github.com/thyagostall/freecell) you're trying to build. Looking at the [package.json](https://github.com/thyagostall/freecell/blob/d73f20acfcce3822afcd7612b67c8a0ff6101b12/package.json) I see that there is no `gulp-concat` among the `devDependencies`. This is probably due to typing:

```
npm install gulp-concat
```

instead of:

```
npm install gulp-concat --save-dev
```

Which would explain why you can build the project locally, but it fails on Travis-CI. Adding the `gulp-concat` to your`devDependencies` should resolve the issue.